# GWT redirect to wrong url

Tags: jsp, gwt

I have a login.jsp page for authentication(using spring-security) to a GWT program.

```
<form name="signinForm" action="<c:url value='/security_check' />" method="post">
```

in client GWT if i receive session expired hint, i use

```
Window.Location.assign(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "login.jsp");
```

to redirecting to sign in page. it works and no problem, but after entering username and password and submit, it send to wrong url

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/myApp/myAppGwtService.rpc
```

and print the following message in browser

```
The call failed on the server; see server log for details
```

tomcat log:

```
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
javax.servlet.ServletException: Content-Type was '(null)'. Expected 'text/x-gwt-rpc'.
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.checkContentTypeIgnoreCase(RPCServletUtils.java:476)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.readContent(RPCServletUtils.java:207)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.readContentAsGwtRpc(RPCServletUtils.java:250)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.readContent(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:182)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:296)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at ir.dpi.bourse.web.view.server.GwtRpcController.handleRequest(GwtRpcController.java:39)
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Also if i wait for some minutes, it works

Answer (score 0):

**solved**
by adding

```
always-use-default-target="true"
```

to

```
<form-login />
```

in spring-security context, but i don't know what was going wrong?

Comment: Hey, is there any chance you figured out what were you doing wrong? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Form authentication in servlets stores in the session the last requested URL, and uses that value as the target to redirect you to after login.

In your case, you called an RPC and it failed because you weren't logged in anymore, and the security filter handled the error by storing the requested URL and redirecting you to the login page (in the AJAX request, so it's hidden to the user). The client code detects this and you redirect the browser to the login page, but the last requested URL is still the RPC.
You could have the same kind of issues if you login page tries to load protected resources (CSS or images for example): after login you'll be redirected to the CSS or image that was tentatively loaded by the login page!

A quick workaround is to just refresh the page (`Window.Location.reload()`) and let the security filter redirect you to the login page. The last URL being loading is the application, so you'll be redirected back to the application.

A better solution IMO is to *not* protect your RPC (at least not with form authentication, but that's not always possible to use several authentication mechanisms in the same webapp, for example if you just use your `web.xml` to configure security) but instead check the current user in the RPC methods and return a specific error to the client (or if done in a servlet filter, you could just return a `401` status code and handle the `StatusCodeException` on the client-side): because the RPC won't be intercepted by the security filter, they won't have the side-effects you experienced.